# how to get a xquery with like?

Tags: xquery

i am trying to get the elements containing the words "Placa Base" ,"micro",memoria" .
i want somthing like that :

```
<placa> 
 <denominacion>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26</denominacion> 
</placa> 
<micro> 
 <denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5-2320</denominacion> 
</micro> 
<micro>
```

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
 for $zone in /productos/produc
let $placa := /productos/produc[contains(lower-case(.),"placa")]/denominacion 
let $micro := /productos/produc[contains(lower-case(.),"micro")]/denominacion 
let $mem := /productos/produc [ contains (lower-case(.),"memoria")]/denominacion 
let $altres:=/productos/produc[ contains(lower-case  (.),"hd")]/denominacion 
let $altres1:=/productos/produc[ contains(lower-case  (.),"tarjeta")]/denominacion 
return <placas><placa>{ data($placa) }</placa>
        <micro>{ data($micro) }</micro>
        <memoria>{ data($mem) }</memoria>
        <altres>{ data($altres) }</altres>
        <altres>{ data($altres1) }</altres>
</placas>
```

but the result was that:

```
<placas>
    <placa>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26 Placa Base ASRock G41M-S3 </placa>
    <micro>Micro Intel Core i5-2320 Micro Intel Core i5 2500 Micro Intel Dual Core G620</micro>
    <memoria>Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 2GB Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 4GB Memoria DDR3 Kingston HyperX 4GB</memoria>
    <altres>HD Seagate Barracuda 250GB SATA HD Caviar Blue 500GB SATA3</altres>
    <altres>Tarjeta gráfica Asus GeForce EN210 Silent 1GB Tarjeta gráfica Gigabyte GeForce 1GB Tarjeta gráfica Nvidia Express 1GB</altres>
</placas>
<placas>
    <placa>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26 Placa Base ASRock G41M-S3 </placa>
    <micro>Micro Intel Core i5-2320 Micro Intel Core i5 2500 Micro Intel Dual Core G620</micro>
    <memoria>Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 2GB Memoria DDR3 G.Skill 4GB Memoria DDR3 Kingston HyperX 4GB</memoria>
    <altres>HD Seagate Barracuda 250GB SATA HD Caviar Blue 500GB SATA3</altres>
    <altres>Tarjeta gráfica Asus GeForce EN210 Silent 1GB Tarjeta gráfica Gigabyte GeForce 1GB Tarjeta gráfica Nvidia Express 1GB</altres>
</placas>
```

......
......
......

Now ,i have the problem on the iteration ,i just want to show the result once .

The xml:

```
<productos>
<TITULO>DATOS DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS</TITULO>
<produc>
<cod_prod>1010</cod_prod>
<denominacion>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26</denominacion>
<precio>50</precio>
<stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
<stock_minimo>3</stock_minimo>
<cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
<cod_prod>1011</cod_prod>
<denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5-2320</denominacion>
<precio>120</precio>
<stock_actual>3</stock_actual>
<stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
<cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: By the way -- the real Right Way to implement this is probably to use a database with full-text search extensions (BaseX supports this, for instance), and to follow the documentation for said extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This took substantial modification to work. I'm providing my answer as a complete, well-formed query (data included) to make it easy to test.

Note that `declare context item` is a new addition in XQuery 3.0.

```
declare context item := document { <productos>
<TITULO>DATOS DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS</TITULO>
<produc>
<cod_prod>1010</cod_prod>
<denominacion>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26</denominacion>
<precio>50</precio>
<stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
<stock_minimo>3</stock_minimo>
<cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
<cod_prod>1011</cod_prod>
<denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5-2320</denominacion>
<precio>120</precio>
<stock_actual>3</stock_actual>
<stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
<cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
</productos>
};
declare variable $words := ("Placa Base", "Micro", "Memoria");

for $zone in /productos/produc
for $word in $words
let $placa := $zone/denominacion[contains(., $word)]
where $placa
return <placa word="{$word}">{data($placa)}</placa>
```

Note that a `for` expression is useless if you then ignore its results and refer to the root again. That is to say, if you're `for $zone in /productos/produc`, then refer to `$zone`, not `/productos/produc`, inside.

Comment: It's a good solution , but they want me to do it in the way I explained in the first message. thank you anyway it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
let $placa := /productos/produc[contains(lower-case(.),"placa")]/denominacion 
let $micro := /productos/produc[contains(lower-case(.),"micro")]/denominacion 
let $mem := /productos/produc [ contains (lower-case(.),"memoria")]/denominacion 
let $altres := /productos/produc[ contains(lower-case  (.),"hd")]/denominacion 
let $altres1 := /productos/produc[ contains(lower-case  (.),"tarjeta")]/denominacion 
return 
  <placas>
    <placa>{ $placa }</placa>
    <micro>{ $micro }</micro>
    <memoria>{ $mem }</memoria>
    <altres>{ $altres }</altres>
    <altres>{ $altres1 }</altres>
  </placas>
```

Comment: Would not `let $deno := $zone/denominacion`, and `let $placa := $zone[...]/...` make far more sense? Why do the assignment inside a FLWOR if you're calculating it from the root each time?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think generally you're right, as far as best-practices go. Was just trying to answer for correctness with minimal changes. Sometimes it's easier to learn one bug at a time ;)

Comment: Your solution launch me this error:effectiveBooleanValue first item of '(true,false,false.....)is not a node.

Comment: @user3325719 I updated the answer to reflect your update; however, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of XQuery and XPath syntax. As mentioned in the other answer, your query misuses the for-loop construct, and that is the main problem. Removing it gives the results that you want. Also, `data()` is not necessary here, and almost never is.